# I am implementing drag and drop functionality please help me.

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am implementing drag and drop functionality in my website using jquery functions and html5.
i want to implement effects on dropable aria like when i will drag image on dropable aria the image that aria contains should expand and when i drop image in that area it should show that image in it. please help me .

Comment: What is this ? Have you tried any thing ? what language are you using ? can you post your code ?

Comment: Please show us your code. Are you using jquery .draggable() ?

Comment: I am trying to implement drag and drop functionality in my website i am developing it in php,jquery,javascript,html5 following is my code:

Comment: html: dropable area: <div class="" style="position: fixed; right:124px; top:60px" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event);expand(this);" ondragover="allowDrop(event);"> <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH_HTTP?>babbler_btn.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"/></a></div>

Comment: html: dragable area: <div class="div-img-box"  ><a href="#" class="blueBtn" id="btn_post_action" rel="post_on_wall-Post" ><img id="drag1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH_HTTP?>lookimag.png" alt="" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"/></a></div>

Comment: jquery functions: function allowDrop(ev) { ev.preventDefault();}function drag(ev) { ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);}function drop(ev){ ev.preventDefault();
 
             do_download(action,wall_id,stat,cnt,user_type);
             ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

Comment: @sameerpatil can you kindly edit your question and post your code block there

Comment: `<!--html: dropable area:--> <div class="" style="position: fixed; right:124px; top:60px" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event);expand(this);" ondragover="allowDrop(event);"> <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH_HTTP?>babbler_btn.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"/></a></div> –`

Comment: `<!--html: dragable area:--> <div class="div-img-box" ><a href="#" class="blueBtn" id="btn_post_action" rel="post_on_wall-Post" ><img id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH_HTTP?>lookimag.png" alt="" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"/></a></div> `

Comment: `/*jquery functions:*/ function allowDrop(ev) { ev.preventDefault();}function drag(ev) { ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);}function drop(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); do_download(action,wall_id,stat,cnt,user_type); ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the .draggable(); function. Also, try to provide us with a working example of a JSfiddle, when adding HTML and jQuery to the comments of your question, it's harder to make sense of it and your question will much more likely not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be help ful

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

// Basic example using the best upload method (Autodetect the best method)

var w = $('someWrap');
var btn = w.getElement('.button.upload');
var originalBtnText = btn.innerHTML;

var myUpload = new DropZone({
    ui_button: w.getElement('.button.upload'),
    ui_drop_area: w.getElement('.button.upload'),
    url: 'upload.php',
    multiple: false,
    //method: 'flash', // DEBUG ONLY
    onUploadStart: function(){

        console.log('ON UPLOAD START!');

        btn.innerHTML = '...';

    },
    onUploadProgress: function(perc){

        console.log('ON UPLOAD PROGRESS: ' + Math.floor(perc) + '%');

        btn.innerHTML = Math.floor(perc) + '%';

    },
    onUploadComplete: function(num_uploaded){

        console.log('ON UPLOAD COMPLETE!');

        btn.innerHTML = 'Uploaded!';

        (function(){
            btn.innerHTML = originalBtnText;
        }).delay(2000);

    }
});


 });
</script>
```

Kindly refer this

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone

Comment: thanks but i am not using dropzone.js